# adding json on a column in enitity class using spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I was using JPA AttributeConverter with Spring Boot 1.2.1 RELEASE and it worked fine. But I get the following error after upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

attributeLabelMap.java:

I want to add this as the json format

```json
metadata: {
          masked: true,
          maxLength: 200,
          formula: "a + b",
          parentCode: "strAttr_1",
          currency: "$",
        },
```

I added this column in entity class

```java
@Column(name = "metadata_json",columnDefinition = "json")
@Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
private Map<String,Object> metaDataAttribute
```

HashMapConverter class:

```java
package in.nobroker.hood.crm.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
public class HashMapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {
        String attributeInfoJson = null;
        try {
            attributeInfoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(stringObjectMap);
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("JSON writing error", e);
        }
        return attributeInfoJson;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        Map<String, Object> attributeInfo = null;
        try {
            attributeInfo = objectMapper.readValue(s, Map.class);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            log.error("JSON reading error", e);
        }
        return attributeInfo;
    }
}
```

In Postman:

```json
{
    "label": "dateAttr_5",
    "id": "f73434ba-bfaa-49f5-9a41-b86715a985f2",
    "filter": true,
    "inUse": true,
    "editable": true,
    "mandatory": true,
    "priority": 0,
    "textOptions": "a,b,c,d",
    "type": "DATETIME_FORM_DATA",
    "filterType": "ABSOLUTE",
    "metaDataAttribute": {
        "masked": true,
        "maxLength": 200,
        "formula": "a + b",
        "parentCode": "strAttr_1",
        "currency": "$"
    }
}
```

I want to add metaDataAttribute when I hit Postman its giving internal server error:

```
argument "content" is null
failed to fetch attribute label mappings 
argument "content" is null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull(ObjectMapper.java:4693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3401)
    at in.nobroker.hood.crm.entity.HashMapConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(HashMapConverter.java:31)
    at in.nobroker.hood.crm.entity.HashMapConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(HashMapConverter.java:10)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.JpaAttributeConverterImpl.toDomainValue(JpaAttributeConverterImpl.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.doConversion(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:140)
    ... 186 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check on String s, in `convertToEntityAttribute` of `HashMapConverter`